# Does there exist a continuous function between the following sets:

Tags: general-topology

Does there exist a continuous  function between the following sets:

$A.f:(-1,1)\rightarrow (-1,1]$ which is onto and one-one

$B.f:\{(x,y):y^2=4x\}\rightarrow \mathbb R$ which is one-one

What topological properties should be used.I am not getting anything .

Comment: $B$ is yes. A parabola is just a curved line....

Comment: As to A, suppose there is such a function. What point maps to $1$?

Comment: Oh yes I missed that very good thanks @HennoBrandsma